# how to do an sql query using values from a dynamic array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

here is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 31
    [1] => 36
    [2] => 41
)
```

the 31,36, and 41 are id's of a record. the elements in this array can be from anywhere of 1 element to 10+ elements. the table structure looks something like this (shortened-version)

```
tbl_cart
---------
id (auto-incremented)
product_name
price
```

what i'm trying to figure out is how can i do a query that will grab the id's listen in a dynamically created array then accumulate the price for each respected id and display the output?

thanks, let me know if this doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to sum the prices for the ids in your list right?

```
$idStr = implode(',', $arr);
$sql = "SELECT sum(price) FROM tbl_cart WHERE id in ($idStr)";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the ids as a comma-separated string using the [**`implode()`**](http://fr.php.net/implode) function, like this :

```
$str_ids = implode(', ', $array);
```

Then, you can inject that into an SQL query, using **`in()`** :

```
select sum(price) as total_price
from tbl_cart
where id in ($str_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$vars = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

$newvars = array();

foreach($vars as $var){

    if(!empty($var))
        $newvars[] = " ID = ".$var;

}

$where = join(" OR ", $newvars);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ".(($where)?"WHERE ".$where: null);

echo $sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = implode(',', $array);
$query = "SELECT id, price FROM tbl_cart WHERE id in ($ids)";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "ID: {$row['id']}  Price: {$row['price']}");  
}
```

Outputs

```
//    ID: 31  Price: (the price)
//    ID: 36  Price: (the price)
//    ID: 41  Price: (the price)
```